# google app engine Deploy failing - Process exited with code 2

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm new to Google App Engine and having troubling understanding their error messages.
I'm using Google App Engine Launcher (on Win XP).
**When I press Deploy (and then sign-in) I get this error message.**

> \pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies',
>   u'--email=by@onetel.com', '--passin', 'update', 'C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Barry\My Documents\test\high-winter-668']" Usage:
>   appcfg.py [options] update  | [file, ...]
>
> appcfg.py: error: Error parsing C:\Documents and Settings\Barry\My
>   Documents\test\high-winter-668\app.yaml: Unable to assign value
>   'http://high-winter-668.appspot.com/' to attribute 'application':
>   Value 'http://high-winter-668.appspot.com/' for application does not
>   match expression
>   '^(?:(?:[a-z\d-]{1,100}\~)?(?:(?!-)[a-z\d-.]{1,100}:)?(?!-)[a-z\d-]{0,99}[a-z\d])$'
>   in "C:\Documents and Settings\Barry\My
>   Documents\test\high-winter-668\app.yaml", line 1, column 14.
>   2014-08-15 17:09:39 (Process exited with code 2)

Can someone tell me what this means please?

My app.yaml file contains:

```
application: http://high-winter-668.appspot.com/
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: high-winter-668.php
```

At https://appengine.google.com/
my "Application" and "Title" both say "high-winter-668"

And in my local application folder C:\Documents and Settings....\high-winter-668\
I have two files:
app.yaml   and high-winter-668.php

Thanks

Comment: Try `application: high-winter-668` (without the `http://..appspot.com/`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use just the app name alone:

```
application: high-winter-668
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: high-winter-668.php
```

This:

```
^(?:(?:[a-z\d-]{1,100}\~)?(?:(?!-)[a-z\d-.]{1,100}:)?(?!-)[a-z\d-]{0,99}[a-z\d])$
```

is a Reg-Ex search pattern

Comment: Thanks - this now works but I ran into a user-password issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387063/google-app-engine-deploy-failing-with-error-1-unauthorised

Answer (score 0):

To add more about app name:
Only lowercase, digits and '-' are allowed and the app name cannot be 
more than 100 characters long.