# Google App Engine - Deploy failing with Error 1: Unauthorised

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm trying to get my first (PHP) application working.  It works OK in Google App Engine Launcher, but when I try to deploy it I get the following message:

```
2014-08-19 15:37:58 Running command: "['C:\\Program Files\\Python\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=by@onetel.com', '--passin', 'update', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Barry\\My Documents\\test\\high-winter-668']"
03:38 PM Application: high-winter-668; version: 1
03:38 PM Host: appengine.google.com
03:38 PM 
Starting update of app: high-winter-668, version: 1
03:38 PM Getting current resource limits.
Password for b...@...com: Invalid username or password.
2014-08-19 15:38:08,967 ERROR appcfg.py:2411 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized. Aborting. 
Error 401: --- begin server output ---
Must authenticate first.
--- end server output ---
```

I can login OK to  the application I created at appengine.google.com

and **I am using the right/same email address and password**.
I can see other topics where server/local time difference is the issue.  My local PC time is the same as the time in the above error msg.

What have I got wrong?

Also:
I tried using appcfg.py on the command line and ran into another issue:
It errored saying I didnt have a "high-winter-668.yaml" file.  So I changed the name of my "app.yaml" to "high-winter-668.yaml" - it then complained that I didnt specify a 'module" in the yaml file.
Meantime Google App Engine Launcher errored say I didnt have an "app.yaml" file.
Are they written by different companies!!??

Comment: post your app.yaml. Check it for spacing and other non-yaml compliant issues.

Comment: The login your using owns the project high-winter-668? Can you include your app.yaml? When its asking for a high-winter-668.yaml its because it thinks you have multiple moduels, each one needs a .yaml file.

Comment: Thanks for both your suggestions - I've found a solution (see below) which hopefully should allow me a little further.

Answer (score 45):

Well, in floundering around I've found an answer.

I went here:
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

and selected "Enable" less secure devices and apps to access your data.
When I tried to Deploy - it worked.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  I was using: `appcfg.py update . --no_cookies`, so I'm guessing this is what flagged it as less secure.

Comment: Thanks, this is it. I think it's a pretty recent change from Google. Hope they will update their App Engine Launcher for that matter.

Comment: just enable Oauth, as per the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

THIS WILL  HAPPEN IF YOU HAVE 2-FACTOR authentication activated. The solution in that case is to go to the [application-specific passwords page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords?pli=1) and generate a new password. You can name it "Google app engine" or the like and you'll get a long alpha string to use as the password when deploying.

If you use Google App Engine Launcher and have 2-factor in use you are guaranteed to run into this error on deploy (current version 1.9.17), and it has been that way for at least 1.5 years. It seems like the app engine launcher folks could trap that error and generate a helpful message but instead maybe you'll find it on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

This happenned to me because I forgot the version line in app.yaml:
version: 1