# Google app engine launcher: Invalid username or password

Tags: google-app-engine

I've download google app engine (python) for windows and install it. Then I went to console.developers.google.com/project and create new project. After that, I launched google app engine launcher, create new application and named it as project I have recently create. I click on deploy and constantly getting this error:

```
  03:35 PM Application: udacity-hello-pozdrav; version: 1
03:35 PM Host: appengine.google.com
 03:35 PM 
Starting update of app: udacity-hello-pozdrav, version: 1
03:35 PM Getting current resource limits.
Password for t******.****@gmail.com: Invalid username or password.
2014-09-06 15:35:56,690 ERROR appcfg.py:2411 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error     401: Unauthorized. Aborting. 
  Error 401: --- begin server output ---
Must authenticate first.
  --- end server output ---
2014-09-06 15:35:56 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

I've read about appcfg.py but when I enter it in cmd, It says that it's not recognized.

Comment: Do you have 2-step authentication turned on? Use application password then.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Would be much better if you will use appcfg.py with `--oauth2` flag.
Like `appcfg.py --oauth2 update /path/to/your/app`.
For the first time you will see the browser window where you'll need to allow access to your account. Then you can deploy without entering any credentials and without confirmations. This will work even with 2-step authentication turned on.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! Still can't get it to deploy from the launcher. Do you know of a way the setup oauth2 in the launcher?

Comment: No, I dont. Still better to use build script with code editor/IDE integration, as for me.

Comment: @Brian: You may try this option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387063/google-app-engine-deploy-failing-with-error-1-unauthorised/25388341#25388341 It worked for me and I can deploy using Launcher.

Answer (score 9):

The "Invalid username or password" error is due to Google security protection. To overcome this error message and be able to deploy from the Launcher, go to your Google Account Settings, then enable "Access for Less Secure Apps" under Security Check Up.

Comment: This worked for me.  At the time that I wrote this comment, the link for the Google Accounts Settings page is https://myaccount.google.com/.  The security option is at the bottom right of the page.